# use variable inside a jquery selector with not()

Tags: jquery, variables, selector

I have a div (id =container) that is containing other divs (many classes)
I am able to use the container as a string "AAAA" but can't do the same effect with a variable mystring

```
<div id="container">
<div class="AAAA">AAAA content</div>
<div class="AAAA">AAAA content</div>
<div class="BBBB">BBBB content</div>
<div class="CCCC">CCCC content</div>
<div class="DDDD">DDDD content</div>
<div class="AAAA">AAAA content</div>
</div>


<script>
var myclass = "#container>div:not("+".AAAA"+")"; // works
$(myclass).css("background-color", "red"); //works fine
//var mystring = "AAAA";
//var myclass = "\"#container>div:not(."+mystring+")\"";
//$(myclass).css("background-color", "red"); // doesn't work
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/xWWcZ/

Reason: you don't need to escape `\#` hash.

Hope rest fits the cause.

**Code**

```
//var myclass = "#container>div:not("+".AAAA"+")"; // works
//$(myclass).css("background-color", "red"); //works fine
var mystring = "AAAA";
var myclass = "#container>div:not(."+mystring+")";
$(myclass).css("background-color", "red"); // work now​​​
```

Comment: thanks guys, I really went over this again and again, I did that before but did not refresh Firefox and thought it was something with my code. now that I saw that i works under jsfiddle.net I was sure the problem was as easy as pressing f5. thanks again

Answer (score 5):

Remove the escaped quotes :

```
var myclass = "#container>div:not(."+mystring+")";
```

Comment: I think you badly tried : this would make the following line exactly the same than the one that worked.